# Submit form using jquery

Tags: jquery, file, forms

I'm trying to submit a form using JQuery. My problem comes from the fact that the front end (html+js/jquery) and the back-end is not on the same site, but it does support JSONP.

The form contains a file input field, so I would be submitting Multi-part form data.
How would you resolve this?

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP ? This is a good start for cross-domain JSON. It should help you to write more specific question. (Currently your question is too general to be answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form action would point to the site controlling the post.

```
<form id="theForm" action="http://someurltoaformsubmitfunction" method="post">
```

then you can call 
`$('#theForm').submit();`

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is submit the form an go to the external site (ie as if you pressed a submit button on a tranditional web form), you can just trigger the form's submit method using Javascript; it doesn't matter where the form posts to.

```
document.myform.submit();
```

However, if you want to post cross-domain using an AJAX-type method, you'll have a harder time of it. The answer lies in using JSONP rather than JSON in your JQuery AJAX requests.

See the [JQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Do not try this, it will not work for cross domain posts.** My fault for not reading the question carefully enough.

Does it have to be a form submit? If not, you could simply do a jQuery ajax call that posts json to it similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourUrl.htm',
    data: 'somethingYouWantToSendToQueryString',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //Do something with the data
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't do an Ajax request cross-domain. Its a security violation in most browsers.

Comment: cripes, i didn't catch that in the question. i'll edit the answer appropriately.