# Submitting a form with a button using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with JS and I have a very simple question.
I want to submit a form with a button which located **outside** of it.

The form header looks like this:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get" id="myform">
```

The button looks like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="send">
```

The JS file is:

```
document.getElementById("send").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
};
```

And it is not working. When I clicked the button nothing happens. 
Any idea? Jquery will be also fine for me instead of vanilla JS.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What you have should work fine, although why not just use a regular `input type="submit"` button within the `form`?

Comment: I hope you haven't write your javascript code about the HTML. in that case, it wouldn't bind the click handler.

Comment: I write it outside with a JS extension. I can't use a regular submit button because the button itself located outside the form (and even in other div element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Prefer using JQuery to submit a form.

There are other posts on stackoverflow covering the topic of submitting a form using JQuery. You can check out this one [Submit form using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979804/submit-form-using-jquery)

If I may add something that might come in handy if you have validators on the form, for required fields for example. You could add a check before you submit the form to see if all the fields are valid. Your button click method may look something like this:

```
function SubmitButtonClick(){
    var form = $('#myForm');
    form.validate();
    if(!form.valid())
      return false;
    else
      form.submit();
})
```

Obviously you should just remember to add the method to the button's onclick like so:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="send" onclick="SubmitButtonClick()" />
```

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer solve it. I forgot to add the onclick="SubmitButtonClick()" inside the input attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("#send").on("click",function () {
  $('#myform').submit();
   });
     });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope this will help you.since your showing google page on button click.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: At least explain that this code will require the addition of a JQuery library!!! Maybe it would be better to stick with basic javascript as that is what the questioner is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try get the id of the form. And you call it from wherver you want.

Try:

```
$(".button").click( function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it with no success :/
I have another JS function for other purpose (which works fine) above this code. Maybe this cause the problem?

Comment: Ofcourse it could affect the the sumit of the form. If you have two forms with submit buttons in the same page you could have issues. Try and move the code higher or in the header just for debugging. The code should be working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("send").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
};}
```

or

```
document.getElementById("send").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myform").submit();}
```

after

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="send">
```